# UI-based memory game

Tags: java, swing

I have created a UI shown in the screenshot. I am initalizing too many `JPanel`s within a panel in my code to achieve the UI which will lead to bad code design and slower performance.

Is there any good practices to follow in writing such a UI?

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class GameUI extends JFrame {

    static JLabel blankCardLabel;
    static JLabel cardOne;
    JLabel cardTwo;
    JLabel cardThree;
    JLabel cardFour;
    JLabel cardFive;
    JLabel cardSix;
    JLabel cardSeven;
    JLabel cardEight;
    JLabel cardNine;
    JLabel cardTen;
    JLabel cardEleven;
    JLabel cardTwelve;
    JLabel cardThirteen;
    JLabel cardFourteen;
     BufferedImage blankCardPic;
    JLabel deck;
     BufferedImage revealCardPic;
    JPanel eastPanel;
    JPanel southPanel;
    JPanel messagePanel;
    JPanel cardPanel;
    BoxLayout eastPanelBL;
    BoxLayout southPanelBL;
    BoxLayout cardPanelBL;
    JLabel playerOne = new JLabel("Player One");
    JLabel playerTwo = new JLabel("Player Two");
    JLabel playerThree = new JLabel("Player Three");
    JLabel playerFour = new JLabel("Player Four");
    JLabel c;
    public GameUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JLabel("Memory Game", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        /*cardOne = new JLabel("One");
        cardTwo = new JLabel("Two");
        cardThree = new JLabel("Three");
        cardFour = new JLabel("Four");
        cardFive = new JLabel("Five");
        cardSix = new JLabel("Six");
        cardSeven = new JLabel("Seven");
        cardEight = new JLabel("Eight");
        cardNine = new JLabel("Nine");
        cardTen = new JLabel("Ten");
        cardEleven = new JLabel("Eleven");
        cardTwelve = new JLabel("Twelve");
        cardThirteen = new JLabel("Thirteen");
        cardFourteen = new JLabel("Fourteen");*/

        deck = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardOne = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardTwo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardThree = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardFour = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardFive = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardSix = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardSeven = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardEight = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardNine = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardTen = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardEleven = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardTwelve = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardThirteen = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));
        cardFourteen = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(blankCard()));


        cardPanel = new JPanel();
        cardPanelBL = new BoxLayout(cardPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardPanelBL);

        JPanel topRowPanel = new JPanel();

        //cardPanel.add(deck);
        //c= new JLabel("Card Left In deck",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        //cardPanel.add(c);

        topRowPanel.add(cardOne);
        topRowPanel.add(cardTwo);
        topRowPanel.add(cardThree);
        topRowPanel.add(cardFour);
        topRowPanel.add(cardFive);
        topRowPanel.add(cardSix);
        topRowPanel.add(cardSeven);
        cardPanel.add(topRowPanel);

        JPanel bottomRowPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardEight);
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardNine);
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardTen);
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardEleven);
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardTwelve);
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardThirteen);
        bottomRowPanel.add(cardFourteen);
        cardPanel.add(bottomRowPanel);


        add(cardPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //cardOne.setBounds(50,50,50,50);
        eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanelBL = new BoxLayout(eastPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        eastPanel.setLayout(eastPanelBL);
        eastPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 20)));
        eastPanel.add(playerOne);
        eastPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        eastPanel.add(playerTwo);
        eastPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        eastPanel.add(playerThree);
        eastPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        eastPanel.add(playerFour);
        add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);  
        southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        southPanel.add(new JTextArea(10,10),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        messagePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        messagePanel.add(new JTextField(10),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        messagePanel.add(new JButton("Send"),BorderLayout.EAST);
        southPanel.add(messagePanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        

        //add(cardOne);
        //cardOne.setText("ClubsAce.png");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setSize(1024,768);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameUI();
    }

    public BufferedImage blankCard() {
        try {
            blankCardPic = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/blank.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return blankCardPic;
    }

    /*public static BufferedImage revealCard(String s) {
        try {
            revealCardPic = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/"+s));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return revealCardPic;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: I don't think a few JPanels can really affect performance... As for code design, I suggest you use an array of JPanels, you'll have one variable instead of 14 for cards, and one instead of 4 for players.

Comment: *"Is there any good practices to follow in writing such a UI?"* This will probably be closed as 'opinion based', but my opinion.. Stop before you reach 10,000 sub-panels. And even then, run it through a profiler before acting. Seriously, this is [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)..

Comment: `public BufferedImage blankCard() {
        try {
            blankCardPic = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/blank.png"));` This method is called multiple times and thus quite inefficient. A better approach (still using the method) is to test the `blankCardPic` for `null` and only try loading it if it is, otherwise just return it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too much 'JPanel's or 'JLabel's or 'JButton's.... the best think that you can do is that you can create array of that. And in for loop you can create it in just few lines if code.